# Pod running in EKS worker node not able to access docker daemon

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a jenkins-slave image in which I have added jenkins to docker group

```
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

And then I use this image in a job as follows

```
podTemplate(label: 'builder-pod-startclust', cloud: 'kubernetes', containers: [
    containerTemplate(
            name: 'jnlp',
            image: "${artifact_repo}/jenkins-slave:ekslave",
            ttyEnabled: true,
            privileged: true,
            alwaysPullImage: true,
            workingDir: '/var/jenkins_home',
            resourceRequestCpu: '1000m',
            resourceRequestMemory: '1Gi',
            resourceLimitMemory: '1.1Gi',
    )
], volumes: [hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run', hostPath: '/var/run')],
   annotations: [
                podAnnotation(key: 'iam.amazonaws.com/role', value: 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/kube2iam-role')
        ]) { //podtemplate
```

However, running docker commands ,eg , `docker version` ,  in the jenkins-slave pod runs into permission issues

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

The jenkins master yaml is as follows

```
containers:
      - name: jenkins-container
        image: $artifact_repo/jenkins:latest
...

     volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/run
                name: docker-sock
```

Comment: I just found this link and i think this might be it https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028151031-Docker-outside-of-Docker-no-longer-works-in-EKS